# Dynamically Change Routing in ASP.NET 6.0 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to take an environmental variable and prefix it to the route for all the controllers. So in Controllers I have the followings:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class DashboardsController : ControllerBase
{.......}
```

Program.cs routing part ==>

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

I have tried creating a class with constant strings and putting into the Route attribute but as you know we cannot change constants, so this didn't work.

Comment: What’s the point? Nothing built in does this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @julealgon's answer, this is the final solution.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class DynamicRouteAttribute : RouteAttribute
    {
        public DynamicRouteAttribute(string template) 
            : base($"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("test")}/{template}")
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(template);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `[Route]` attribute implements a `IRouteTemplateProvider` interface, which defines a `Template` property that returns the route template.

If you implement a custom attribute, say `[DynamicRoute]`, that takes an environment variable name as a parameter, you could set the `Template` property to a different value based on the environment variable passed in.

This works for me:

```cs
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class DynamicRouteAttribute : Attribute, IRouteTemplateProvider
    {
        public DynamicRouteAttribute(string environmentVariableName)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(environmentVariableName);

            Template = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(environmentVariableName);
        }

        public string? Template { get; }

        public int? Order { get; set; }

        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Replace `[Route("[controller]")]` in your controller with `[DynamicRoute("yourEnvVarName")]` and it will start to honor whatever you configure in your environment variable.

Comment: Thank you ! I tried it, made some changes (inheriting from RouteAttribute), and It worked!