# Add environment variables to swagger at c#

Tags: c#

I'm using postman and I have options there for using environment variables like thoese:

1. add at a Url {{something}}/Url...
2. the same like 1 but use an environment variable inside the body request.

how can I implement that in the swagger?
my code is at c#, asp.net
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically Change Routing in ASP.NET 6.0 Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72532465/dynamically-change-routing-in-asp-net-6-0-web-api)

Comment: no, because I can have for example this POST request at postman: {
  "recipientsUUIDs": [
    "{{userId}}"
  ],
  "notificationType": "EMAIL",
  "templateName": "TimeOffRequest",
  "parameters": {
    "MESSAGE": "Example Message"
  },
  "subject": "POC from IntegrationService"
}
and I want that the swagger will know {{userId}}